# User generated nested dictionaries (Hashes) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary

Pardon my ignorance, but how would I begin to go about creating the following type of dictionary:

```
"please give your new library a name"
French
```

what I want is to then create a new hash as the value to the key French `{ "French" => "{}" }`

as then in the value to key French it could be updated to look like `{ {"hello" => "bonjour", "bonjour" => "hello"}, {"good" => "bon", "bon" => "good}, ... }`

I hope you can see what I am trying to do. Perhaps I am going about this the completely wrong way?

Edit... perhaps something along these lines?

```
puts "please give your new library a name"
user_libs = Hash.new
sub = gets.chomp
user_libs[sub] = {}
puts user_libs
```

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. Your code shows that you know how to create a new hash generated by user input. The only missing part is automatically populating it with English/French word pairings. Is your question how to magically come up with this list of pairings based on the word "French"?

Comment: My code shows that I carried on trying to work out how to do this before anyone answered. hence the Edit... I used the word "French" as an example as I did not / still do not understand the syntax. No magic im afraid ;) my question is two fold, is this a good way of storing data, and soncondly - how do i now edit the nested dictionary after creating it. I am finding clear examples of ruby code far harder to find than python, but perhaps that is just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "please give your new library a name: "
name = gets.chomp
h = {name => {}}
print "enter word pairs: " #hello bonjour
while (input = gets.chomp) != ""
  k,v = input.split(" ")
  h[name][k] = v
end
p h
```

Comment: is `h[name][k] = v` the syntax for how to go into the nested hash?

Comment: Yes. Actually it consists of two methods, `#[]` and `#[]=`.

Comment: exactly! perfect... I am glad you understood! :)